# Unable to access Hive JDBC remotely after SSL configured on Hive

Tags: hadoop, ssl, jdbc, hive

I have enabled SSL on Hive and after that, I've tried connecting to the HIVE through JDBC from DBeaver using below connection Urls.

```
URL1: "jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=<path-to-truststore>;trustStorePassword=<password>"

URL2: "jdbc:hive2://hostname:10000/default;ssl=1" 


**Error for Url1**: " Unexpected driver error occurred while connecting to database
Illegal character in path at index 57: hive2://dummyhost:00000/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=D:\cert\cmhost-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=xyz"

**Error for Url2**:Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.180:10000/default;ssl=1: Invalid status 21
Invalid status 21
```

Please correct me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Usually port 10000 is used for **binary** transport, which does not use SSL encryption. Also, Windows paths should be passed to Java apps using Linux separator i.e. `/` or with escaped back-slash i.e. ` \\ ` _(damn that shitty markdown used by StackOverflow... Can't escape the escape char properly)_

Comment: SSL options apply only to (optional) **HTTP** transport, usually on port 10001, and with mandatory HTTP-specific flags in the URL. Read. The. Docs.

Comment: Thanks your reply. I have tried the suggested changes in the HTTP transport port and used port as "10001". Even after the changes it is not connecting. Please find the below error message.  ERROR: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: "jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.180:10001/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=D:/cert/cmhost-keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=password: Could not connect to 192.168.0.180 on port 10001; Could not connect to 192.168.0.180 on port 10001; Connection refused: connect". FYI, I'm using Hive from cloudera setup.

Comment: Are you using the Apache driver or the Cloudera driver? URL syntax is different. Did you google for the flags to enable SSL debug trace in Java? That helps because default error messages are not helpful. Did you check that you actually could contact the port, and are not blocked by a firewall?

Comment: I'm using Apache driver. The URL syntax which I have used is provided by cloudera for SSL JDBC URL.  I have got below flag where I'm not aware of adding the myclass in the flag  **`java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/usr1/ssl/trust_store.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xyz \
 MyClass jdbc:hive2://localhost:10001/default;ssl=true`** . I would like to request you to help me where I can find the MYCLASS for hive jdbc